# Owner of Transcend multimedia device changes to root, no change operations are permitted under Ubuntu

Tags: usb, mount, permissions

So far, when I have attached the Transcend external media player to USB port of my Ubuntu 12.04 machine, it always got mounted with the ownership of current user, permitting all write operations. But suddenly, this device is being mounted with `root` ownership. This makes all write operations *not* permitted unless you become the `root` user. That it not something I will want to permit to everyday users.

Anyway, `/etc/mtab` shows the device mounted like this,

```
/dev/sde /media/usb0 vfat rw,noexec,nodev,sync,noatime,nodiratime 0 0
/dev/sdd /media/usb1 vfat rw,noexec,nodev,sync,noatime,nodiratime 0 0
```

There is no entry for this in `/etc/fstab` so the scenario is happening from a default setting after recent upgrade.

Further details on the device (`df -hT`),

```
/dev/sde       vfat      922M  385M  537M  42% /media/usb0
/dev/sdd       vfat      7.3G  7.1G  229M  97% /media/usb1
```

The other usb devices like external hard drives get mounted with the ownership of current user, no problem.

After mounting of the Transcend device, the operations

```
sudo chown -vR <user>:<user> /media/usb0
sudo chown -vR <user>:<user> /media/usb1
```

failed, as they should.

I have already taken a look at these answers, [1](https://superuser.com/questions/255723/how-to-change-the-owner-permission-of-device-files), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/57092/cant-change-permission-ownership-group-of-external-hard-drive-on-ubuntu), [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230031/usb-devices-and-flash-disks-mount-as-root-instead-of-the-user), without any avail.

As intructed in the last one, I even tried running the command,

```
sudo usermod -a -G plugdev,fuse masroor
```

But that did not improve the scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search and agony, I found from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1770757) that [usbmount](http://usbmount.alioth.debian.org/) was the offending package causing all this unnecessary trouble.

Once I uninstalled `usbmount`,

```
sudo apt-get purge usbmount
```

things are good again.

It appears that `usbmount` is not even needed in a desktop version. It is [needed in a server though](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB#Automounting_.28Ubuntu_Server.29). And the mount-as-root feature in a server is very much applicable.

I am not sure how `usbmount` was installed in my machine.