# USB drive auto-mounted by user but gets write permissions for root only

Tags: unity, 13.04, usb-drive, gvfs, udisks

I am trying to use my ext4 USB drive but Ubuntu 13 is currently mounting it with write permission only for root so with my normal user I can't write to it, without sudo.

The first place I checked was `dconf-editor` which has the following options

- automount
- automount-open
- autorun-never
- autorun-x-content-ignore
- autorun-x-content-open-folder
- autorun-x-content-start-app

and it seems to me there should be an option in there to control if I can write to the mounted USB drive, but no.

I also made sure my user is in the relevant groups: `fuse` and `plugdev`

I've searched most of the internet and can't find a solution to change the permissions given by the mount operation. There's literally nobody out there having this problem incredibly. A ton of people have issues because their drives mounts totally read-only, but not this way with only root write permission.

I can't see any way of controlling what happens. I looked at setting the mount options using `gnome-disks` but drew a blank.

It's not in `fstab` but it does appear in the `mount` list or /etc/mtab:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/adam/WDPassport2T ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2 0 0
```

This is what appears in syslog if it helps:

```
kernel: [111522.196770] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 6
kernel: [111525.384020] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
kernel: [111525.565220] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=0820
kernel: [111525.565225] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
kernel: [111525.565227] usb 2-1: Product: My Passport 0820
kernel: [111525.565229] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Western Digital
kernel: [111525.565231] usb 2-1: SerialNumber:  575832314141334A34383631
kernel: [111525.565729] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
kernel: [111525.566203] scsi9 : usb-storage 2-1:1.0
mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1"
mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 7 was not an MTP device
kernel: [111526.564697] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Passport 0820 1007 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
kernel: [111526.565063] scsi 9:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1007 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
kernel: [111526.568096] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
kernel: [111526.568202] ses 9:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
kernel: [111526.568263] ses 9:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 13
kernel: [111531.263108] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] 3906963456 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
kernel: [111531.265100] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
kernel: [111531.265105] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
kernel: [111531.266473] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
kernel: [111531.266479] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
kernel: [111531.272224] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
kernel: [111531.272230] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
kernel: [111531.284885]  sdb: sdb1
kernel: [111531.288219] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
kernel: [111531.288223] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
kernel: [111531.288227] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
kernel: [111531.751588] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
udisksd[3131]: Mounted /dev/sdb1 at /media/adam/WDPassport2T on behalf of uid 1000
```

Comment: Try running `sudo umount /dev/sdb1`, and then mounting it as a normal user. The `mtab` entry has `user=adam`, which should mean user `adam` can use it...

Comment: @wilf actually it's the second mtab entry that has user=adam, not the USB drive. I don't know what that gvfsd-fuse stuff is. Probably irrelevant but I am puzzled why one entry has it, but not the usb drive.

Comment: Whoops... Should pay more attention. The entries themselves are fine, so it should work... Do you mount and unmount the drive graphically, or via command line? - running `gvfs-mount -d /dev/sdb1` should mount the drive, also should `udisks --mount /dev/sda5`. These should not require the root password, as they use the `gvfsd` entry to allow access.

Comment: so gvfs does have something to do with it. i am currently mounting and unmounting the drive graphically via nautilus, but i actually want it to be done automatically on attachment so that the backupdb process can use the drive. occurs to me that this is another problem even if i get the write permissions sorted.

Comment: @wilf just in case this trips anything in your mind, `gvfs-mount -d /dev/sdb1` mounts it just like nautilus on the GUI, i.e. with root write permissions only. `udisks --mount /dev/sdb1` mounts it too but in the wrong place (without the user name directory under /media), also with root write permissions only.

Comment: @Adam, what's the filesystem type of your USB device? and what does `ls -ld /media/adam/WDPassport2T` and `ls -l /media/adam/WDPassport2T` output?

Comment: `adam@gondor:~$ ls -ld /media/adam/WDPassport2T`

`drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jan 15 16:57 /media/adam/WDPassport2T`

Comment: `adam@gondor:~$ ls -l /media/adam/WDPassport2T`

`total 20`

`drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jan 15 16:57 backuppc`

`drwx------ 2 root root 16384 Jan 15 15:37 lost+found`

Comment: @hash it's ext4. what do you suspect?

Comment: lsb_release -a
...
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:        14.04

ls -ld /media/user1/
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 user1 user1 4096 jan.  27 22:40 /media/user1/

id -a
uid=1000(user1) gid=1000(user1) groups=1000(user1),... 46(plugdev),107(fuse)...

ls -ld /media/user1/*
drwx------ 3 user1 user1 32768 jan.   1  1970 /media/user1/9016-4EF8

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A possible reason could be that you formatted/created the storage disk with a tool with root privilege and so the file-system created was owned by the *root*.

Let's have a look at the o/p of your `ls` commands:

```
$ ls -ld /media/adam/WDPassport2T
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jan 15 16:57 /media/adam/WDPassport2T
$ ls -l /media/adam/WDPassport2T
total 20 
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 15 16:57 backuppc 
drwx------ 2 root root 16384 Jan 15 15:37 lost+found
```

The file-system is owned by the root, as indicated by `ls -ld` for your mount *WDPassport2T* and the [permission string](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397493/what-does-the-first-of-the-10-character-of-unix-style-permission-string-indicate/404939#404939) `drwxr-xr-x` shows the owner *root* has the RW permissions while, the members of group *root* along with the world/others will only have R-permission.

To solve you could change the permissions with `chmod` or just change the ownership recursively, and this is what I've shown below:

```
sudo chown <username>:<groupname> -R /path/to/target
```

which in your case would be:

```
sudo chown adam:adam -R /media/adam/WDPassport2T/
```

Now if you need, you may also set the permissions with `chmod`:

```
find /media/adam/WDPassport2T/ -type f -execdir chmod 666 -Rv {} +
```

*(which gives owner, group and the world RW permissions for all the files in the target.)*

```
find /media/adam/WDPassport2T/ -type d -execdir chmod 777 -Rv {} +
```

*(which gives owner, group and the world RWX permissions for all the directories in the target.)*

#### Reference:

[Official Ubuntu Documentation: File Permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions)

Comment: Fantastic. I didn't think of trying that because I just assumed the file permissions on /media/adam/WDPassport2T were set by the mount process, i.e. I didn't realise the actual USB drive (or its allocated mount point) would obtain and keep permissions. So there would be similar issues with permissions / ownership if I plugged the disk into another box?

Comment: @Adam: _"...would there be issues with permissions/ownership if I plugged the disk into another box?"_ well I'm not sure so I posted this Q: [How portable are the works chmod and chown commands?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109723/how-portable-are-the-works-chmod-and-chown-commands) ..if want to have RW permissions for the files/directories in other systems as well, you could allow RW for the world/othrs using `chmod`, please refer to the updated answer...

Comment: If I formatted a USB drive ext4 using `gksu gparted`, would that automatically make me the owner of that USB drive, or would if still be formatted with root as owner?

Comment: This doesn't work.  I am still getting operation not permitted when I try and chown anything on that mount point.

Comment: But the question is why is the drive *mounted* as root in the first place. Is there a setting I can set so that in the future the drive is mounted by my user instead?

Comment: I get `chown: changing ownership of 'NO_NAME': Operation not permitted` when I use `sudo chown alex NO_NAME`

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried re-formating the drive with your own permissions?

First, check your user id:

```
sudo id -u red
```

It should give "1000"

Next, unmout the drive in filemanager.

Be careful, **you will lose all your data** with the next comand

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdx1 -E root_owner=1000:1000
```

Mount the drive and you should be able to write files and folders

Comment: This, actually, should be the primary answer, because it addresses the root problem of why the OS creates the /media/user-id/mount-point directory with the owner being root in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

Most partitioning & formatting tools (like Gparted) requires the root privileges.

File systems like ext4, ext3 stores file ownership information with the pen drive itself. (But the ntfs, fat32, fat16 does not have a security like that)

In this case you have to change the permission by using the following command in the terminal.

```
chown -hR nobody:nogroup /media/adam/WDPassport2T/
```

by setting the user as "nobody" & the group as "nogroup" it will fix the similar issues with permissions / ownership when plugged the disk into another box.

for more info see the manual page for chown command (use "`man chown`" )

Comment: It's `nobody` alright. But my user id isn't nobody, and it is preventing me to write.

Answer (score 0):

The file-system is owned by the root, as indicated by ls -ld for your mount WDPassport2T and the permission string drwxr-xr-x shows the owner root has the RW permissions while, the members of group root along with the world/others will only have R-permission.